# Store __m256i to integer

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

How can I store __m256i data type to integer?

I know that for floats there is :

```
_mm256_store_ps(float *a, __m256 b)
```

where the first argument is the output array.

For integers I found only :

```
_mm256_store_si256(__m256i *a, __m256i b)
```

where both arguments are __m256i data type.

Is it enough to do something like this:

```
int * X = (int*) _mm_malloc( N * sizeof (*X) ,32 );
```

( I am using this as an argument to a function and I want to obtain it's values)

Inside function:

```
__m256i * Xmmtype = (__m256i*) X;

//fill output
_mm256_store_si256( &Xmmtype[ i ] , T ); //T is __m256i
```

Is this OK?

-----UPDATED -----------------------

Ok, so what if I have :

```
__m256i T;

for ( y = 0; y < h; y++ )
{ 
    for ( x = 0; x < w; x++ )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < N; i+=8 )
        {
            //calculate here the  T

        } 

        //write result
        _mm256_store_si256( &Xmmtype[ x + y * w ] , T );


    } 

}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you've done is OK, but you don't need to create a temporary pointer - you can just apply the cast directly, e.g.:

```
_mm256_store_si256( (__m256i *)X, T );
```

or:

```
_mm256_store_si256( (__m256i *)&X[i], T );
```

---

Update based on the latest edit of your question:

It looks like you are indexing `X` in a way that does not meet AVX alignment requirements, i.e. `X[i]` is not guaranteed to be 32 byte aligned, so you should use an unaligned store:

```
_mm256_storeu_si256( (__m256i *)&X[i], T );
```

Comment: :Hello , it gives me segmentation fault applying the casting.

Comment: That's probably a different problem - you need to make sure that `X` (or `&X[i]`) is 32 byte aligned, or use `_mm256_storeu_si256` instead of `_mm256_store_si256` if you can't guarantee alignment.

Comment: I have used _mm_malloc( N * sizeof (*X) ,32 ).It is 32 aligned ,right?I will try also the storeu and let you know.( I will be able to test it next week though)

Comment: If you're using `X[i]` then `i` will need to be a multiple of 8 to maintain alignment.