# Turn _m256i into int array

Tags: c++, intel, sse, avx, avx2

I'm currently using AVX2 and I have the following problem:

After doing some AVX instructions I have to extract all values and put them into an array, the problem is that the way I found to do it isn't efficient at all...

I did the following things:

```
uint32_t temp[];
__m256i x, y;
temp[0] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 0);
temp[1] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 1);
temp[2] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 2);
temp[3] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 3);
temp[4] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 4);
temp[5] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 5);
temp[6] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 6);
temp[7] = _mm256_extract_epi32(x, 7);
```

Is there a way to do it better ?

Thanks.

Comment: memcpy, possibly with a shuffle first?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I googled a bit and found [**`_mm256_storeu_si256() `**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/695239) due to this Q/A: [SO: Store __m256i to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517684/7478597)

Comment: oops sorry... Didn't saw that post, Thanks for the answer!