# How to get a __m256i AVX container to override an array of 8-bit integers?

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx, avx2

There is an instruction called `_mm256_set1_epi8` in AVX which can set 32 8-bit integers inside a `_m256i` container to a specific value.

If I have an array of said 8-bit integers, how can I make it so that the `__m256i` container resulting from the `_mm256_set1_epi8` operation overrides the `char[32]` container ?

I have not found any load or move instruction related to epi8 (8-bit signed integers) in either SSEx, or AVX. I guess there must be a way to achieve this as it seems not that complicated of a computation but I cannot find which instruction should be used to achieve that.

If it is not achievable using `__m256i`, would it be possible to achieve something similar with a `__m128i` ?

Code sample to illustrate the situation described above :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  // This is an array of 8-bit signed integers
  char charArray[32] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, /*[...],*/ 30, 31 };

  // This is the value I want to set in the array at some point
  char valueToSet = 4;

  // This instruction makes it possible to set 32 8-bit signed integers at once
  __m256i eightBitIntegersRegistry = _mm256_set1_epi8(valueToSet);

  // How can I make it affect the charArray array?
  // In the end I would want the content of charArray to be { 4, 4, 4, [...] 4, 4, 4 }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is fairly similar to [Store __m256i to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517622/store-m256i-to-integer), it doesn't matter whether it's char or int or whatever, just cast the pointer. The alignment or lack of it does matter.

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks a lot ! I'm not sure how to know if my array is memory-aligned or not so I'll try `_mm256_storeu_si256` by default.

Comment: I can confirm the other question's answer solves this. I think I should probably let this one up nonetheless as the other one is poorly named and didn't come up in my search ?