# how to convert `__m256i` to `int`

Tags: c++, avx

I want to convert the bits stored in `__m256i` to `int[]`
I've tried`_mm256_storeu_si256 ((__m256i*)rd,rs)` but it seems to fail.

### So what's the reason behind it? And what is the correct way to convert __m256i to 8 integers?

Here is the context:

```
//a, b are two arrays(larger than 8)
__m256i rs1 = _mm256_loadu_si256 ((const __m256i*) (a + (i+k)*sizeof(int)));// load 256bits rs1
__m256i rs2 = _mm256_loadu_si256 ((const __m256i*) (b + i*sizeof(int)));// load 256bits to rs2
__m256i rd = _mm256_maddubs_epi16 (rs1, rs2);// computation (each entry in a/b is positive and smaller than 8 so I think it is valid)
_mm256_storeu_si256 ((__m256i*)result,rd);// store the result to the result[] (it crash)
```

it reports `segmentation fault`

---

Ive looked up [Store __m256i to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517622/store-m256i-to-integer), but I guess we have different problem (what I am doing is same with it)

---

next, I try `_mm256_extract_epi32`--store integers one by one(it is stupid but I have no way), and it works?????GG

Comment: why not `_mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)rd, rs)`?

Comment: cause I can't make sure whether the data is aligned

Comment: Could you give some more context here, I have no idea what `rd` and `rs` are or their types.

Comment: @Cino `_mm256_storeu_si256` for unaligned

Comment: Crashes how?  Where is your `int result[8]` array?  Don't think of it as *converting*, think of it as *storing* into a C++ array.  What you do with that C++ array afterward is up to you.  I added a few more duplicate links that show more complete examples of getting data out of a SIMD vector and using it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I cannot follow. yes, it this function is storing 256 bits to int*. my result[8] is defined above, just `int result[8];` and what do you mean by `I added a few more duplicate links`?