# error: invalid static_cast from type ‘__m256i’ {aka ‘__vector(4) long long int’} to type ‘void*’

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx, low-level

I'm trying to compile a piece of code where it calls uses `static_cast` to do something like the following:

```
  __m256i values;
  int64_t i = 1;
  static_cast<void*>(values + i);
```

but this results in the error:

> error: invalid static_cast from type ‘__m256i’ {aka ‘__vector(4) long
> long int’} to type ‘void*’

It appears this conversion invalid or `static_cast` is not appropriate here? Is there an alternative approach to perform the conversion?

This is pretty low level stuff, and I'm not too familiar with this.

Comment: It looks like a compiler extension where `__m256i` is a `typedef` for 4 `long long int`s to form a 256 bit integer type. It also looks like you are trying to cast whatever value `values` holds + `i` into a `void*`. You'd need `reinterpret_cast<void*>(values + i)` for that, but it looks risky

Comment: when you say 4 `long long ints`, do you mean `__m256i` is an array like structure, which would mean `values` is a pointer?

Comment: @TedLyngmo forgot to tag you in the previous comment

Comment: A compiler might accept `static_cast<void*>(values + i);` on a system with 256 bit addressing. Perhaps this code originates in something other than a conventional desktop x86-derived computer. Maybe GPU. Anyway, one big mother of an address.

Comment: Maybe related: [Store __m256i to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517622/store-m256i-to-integer)

Comment: Sorry, the code doesn't make sense. Maybe it is a typo (missing `&` somewhere?), maybe plain wrong. You will need to show more context before we can attempt to guess what this code is trying to achieve.

Comment: No, `values` is *not* like a pointer.  It's like a struct or class, it's a value not a pointer.  Did you want to do something like GNU C `values[i]` to index one of the 64-bit elements?  See [print a \_\_m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46752535) for why `reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&values)[i]` would be strict-aliasing undefined behaviour.  (Although that should compile and might work.)  See also [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605)

Comment: But anyway, `__m256i` is not a value type that it makes sense to cast to a pointer value.  Adding a scalar `int64_t` with `+` *does* compile in GNU C++, as equivalent to `_mm256_add_epi64(value, _mm256_set1_epi64(i));`  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html

Comment: @David I got your "ping" now. It seems Peter et al. has done an excellent job here already. I've got nothing to add to what's been said so far :-)