# What is `__vector(4) long long int`?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is related to [error: invalid static_cast from type ‘__m256i’ {aka ‘__vector(4) long long int’} to type ‘void*’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71684373/error-invalid-static-cast-from-type-m256i-aka-vector4-long-long-int).

The compiler error I got is

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘__m256i’ {aka ‘__vector(4) long long int’} to type ‘void*’
```

What does the `__vector` mean?

Comment: @lurker. No. I don't know what "4 long long ints" in the comment in that post means. It sounds like it's an array structure, but what does `__vector` represent under the hood?

Comment: Recommendation remove the *What is __vector(4) long long int?* bit from the other question and people will be a lot less likely to close as a duplicate. The other question is asking 2 questions and should only ask one, the problem with the `static_cast`. The other question is asked here. Going to pre-emptively reopen.

Comment: Asking second question, identical to the first one (except maybe with less details and not self-contained), is not the correct way to go about unanswered question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Side note: I have some guesses, but I'm going to have to leave this one for the compiler wonks who don't have to make guesses.

Comment: Since you are dealing with an identifier containing a double underscore, you should probably mention your OS and compiler. (These identifiers are reserved, so their meaning is often dependent on the toolchain.)

Comment: It means whatever your C++ compiler thinks it means, this is a symbol that's used internally by your C++ compiler and library, you'll have to hunt down any documentation, or browse the internal header files to locate its definition.

Comment: keywords: SIMD, AVX

Comment: It's something like compiler internal `struct { private: long long int reserved[4]; }`.

Answer (score 0):

`__vector` is not anything defined in the C++ language. It is a name reserved to the language implementation.

It may be an implementation detail, or it may be a language extension. If it is the latter, then it should be documented by the language implementation. I recommend starting with the documentation of your compiler.